# simplexml_load_file failed to open stream Http request failed

Tags: simplexml, php

i am trying to parse xml from twitter feeds and it was working fine and suddenly i started to get this:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23jan26): 
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 420 unused in /var/www/test.php 
>   on line 20

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying this same request with curl or even in a browser from the same IP as this script is runnign and looking at the body of the error message.

However this is generally the result of rate limiting, meaning you're reqesting too often. YOu can see similar issues [here](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/26326a163c19c7dc/4f04a4c30680216d?lnk=gst&q=not+in+search&pli=1).